# How can I take a count of status in distinct delivery nos. in mogodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

A collection is having del no. with multiple status. I need to take the count of each status that has occured in distinct del no. ?

Comment: we only understand data

Comment: please post some sample data

Answer (score 0):

db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$**YOUR_STATUS_FIELD_NAME**",count:{$sum:1}}}])